# Get dropdown selected value to textbox in mvc3 jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have one drop downlist and text box in my view. now i have to set selected value of dropdownlist to textbox using jquery. i should not post back. i am learning mvc3 . so give me optimal way of doing it.

Comment: You need to learn Javascript and jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to postback you will need to use javascript. For example if you use jQuery you could subscribe to the [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event of the dropdown and set the value of the textbox:

```
$(function() {
    $('#id_of_your_drop_down').change(function() {
        var selectedValue = $(this).val();
        $('#id_of_your_text_box').val(selectedValue);
    });
});
```

I would also recommend you going through the getting started tutorials in the [jQuery documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials) as this is quite basic functionality.

Comment: i am sorry for the late reply. actually how to place this jquery inside view or should place in js file then add reference?

Comment: its nice i just add it js and add reference in view. it works like a charm. thanks